# How do I avoid this sample error when creating classification trees in Rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny, tree, classification

I'm working on a task right now to create an Rshiny app to do a couple of things. Specifically, I'm having trouble with creating the classification tree's in the "Classification tools" tab, without getting any errors.

The classification tree output is supposed to be dependent on a slideInput which determines the proportion of training data that the tree uses. Currently, the code almost works fully as 4/5 of the slide inputs work correctly to create a classification plot. However, when I set the slide to 0.5, I get the following error: *cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE*

Here is my code:

```
data <- read.csv("Fatality-task2.csv")

data$Rate <- as.factor(data$Rate)

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(markdown)
library(gtsummary)
library(ggdendro)
library(factoextra)
library(mclust)
library(cluster)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

#################################################################


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("",
             tabPanel("Data Exploration",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput("variable",
                                      "Variable",
                                      colnames(data)),
                          selectInput("rate",
                                      "Rate",
                                      levels(data$Rate))
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tableOutput("table"),
                          plotOutput("plot")
                        )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Classification tools",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput("train.prop",
                                      "Training data proportion",
                                      min = 0.4,
                                      max = 0.8,
                                      step = 0.1,
                                      value = 0.6)
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          plotOutput("plot2")
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)




#################################################################


server <- function(input, output) {
  sum <- reactive({
    data <- data %>%
      filter(Rate == input$rate) %>%
      select(input$variable) %>%
      summary() %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      tidyr::separate(Freq, c("Stat", "Value"), sep=":") %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from =Stat, values_from = Value)
    data <- data[, -c(1,2)]
    
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$variable == "jaild" | input$variable == "Rate"){
    ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, fill = .data[[input$variable]])) +
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
        if (input$variable == "Rate"){
          theme(legend.position = "none")
        }
    } else {
      ggplot(data, aes(x = Rate, y = .data[[input$variable]], fill = Rate)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
    }
    
    
  })
  
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    n <- nrow(data)
    ind1 <- sample(c(1:n), round(n*input$train.prop))
    ind2 <- sample(c(1:n)[-ind1], round(n*(1-input$train.prop)))
    
    train.data <- data[ind1,]
    
    valid.data <- data[ind2,]
    
    fit.tree <- rpart(Rate~., data = train.data, method = "class")
    
    rpart.plot(fit.tree)
  })
  

  
  
  
}




#################################################################
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The issue occurs in the code following 'output$plot2'

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to happen when the error occurs? Also it looks like you're sampling x% of the data, then sampling 100-x% on the remaining values... does this make sense?

If you sample 20% of the data for ind1, don't you want everything else for ind2? The current code is taking 20% of the data for ind1, then taking 80% of the _remaining_ data for ind2.

Comment: Actually you helped me realise my mistake. I didn't realise I was only taking 80% of the remaining data for ind2. I've changed my code and now all the inputs are working so I think it looks right now. Thanks a lot